# I want to fetch checkbox values from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch checkbox values from mysql database . I have tried loop and array but it's not working

**Here My Php Code**

```
  <form action="" name="color1" id="color1" method="post"> 
  <br />
  <?php
  $count=10;
  $querycolor=mysql_query("select color,id from products order by id");
  while($rowcolor=mysql_fetch_array($querycolor))
  $count++;
  {
  for($i=0; $i<=count; $i++) {    
  $colors=$rowcolor['color'][$i];
  $colorid=$rowcolor['id'];
  }
   ?>
 <input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="" onclick="window.location='search.php?<?php echo $colors ?>';"><?php echo $rowcolor['color'];?><br /> 
 <?php }?>       
 </form>
```

**For Example  I Want To Display Checkbox Values Like This**

```
1) White (2)<br>
2) Black (3)<br>
3) Blue (10)<br>
```

Comment: 'but with numbers' what is number here?

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_*` functions: they're deprecated (see the [red box](http://php.net/mysql_query)). BTW, the `font` element is deprecated.

Comment: @akam i want to display checkbox values like this.

1) White (2)<br>
2) Black (3)<br>
3) Blue (10)<br>

Comment: You need count function see it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @MadaraUchiha sorry i'm new at stackoverflow i don't understand mysql_*?

Comment: All functions that start with `mysql_` are deprecated.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel ok sorry and thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [COUNT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html) function:

Query:

```
SELECT count(id) as cnt, color, id
FROM products 
GROUP By color
order by id
```

Then you can print cnt like `$rowcolor['cnt'];`

Comment: akam how to display numbers with color names?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
<form action="" name="color1" id="color1" method="post"> 
  <br />
  <?php
  $count=10;
  $querycolor=mysql_query("select color,id from products order by id");
  while($rowcolor=mysql_fetch_array($querycolor))
  $count++;
  {
  for($i=0; $i<=$count; $i++) {    
  $colors=$rowcolor['color'][$i];
  $colorid=$rowcolor['id'];
         ?>
 <input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $colors.'('.$colorid.')';?>" onclick="window.location='search.php?<?php echo $colors ?>';"><?php echo $rowcolor['color'];?><br /> 
 <?php } } ?>       
 </form>
```

Hope this helps